# Strange thing using simple test in Php

Tags: php, simpletest

file1:

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once('simpletest/web_tester.php');

class TestOfRankings extends WebTestCase {
    function tesetWeAreTopOfGoogle() {
        $this->get('http://poll:8888/index.php/admin/unit_test');
        $this->assertText('this is good');
    }
}
?>
```

file2:

```
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once('simpletest/web_tester.php');

class MakTest extends WebTestCase {
    function testOneAndOneMakesTwo() {
        $this->get('http://poll:8888/index.php/admin/unit_test');
        $this->assertText('this is good');
    }
}
```

almost identical files, why do they give me different result?

```
file1.php
OK
Test cases run: 0/2, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Exceptions: 0


file2.php
OK
Test cases run: 1/2, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Exceptions: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SimpleTest docs](http://simpletest.org/en/start-testing.html):

> When a test case runs, it will search for any method that starts with the string "test" and execute that method. If the method starts "test", it's a test.

In `file1` the function name is `tesetWeAreTopOfGoogle` (this seems to be a typo).  Switch to `testWeAreTopOfGoogle` and you'll be golden.

Comment: Haha nice one!  Wonder where you got that from.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions probably need to start with test.  tesetWeAreTopOfGoogle should be testWeAreTopOfGoogle?

Comment: "Probably?"  Do you have any experience with simpletest?